# Is there a way to make large symbols look better in superscripts and subscripts?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, large-symbols

I want to include a summation in the exponent. The following code I use now produce a somewhat uncanny-looking result:

```
\begin{align*}
    $x^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k}}$ \\
    $x_{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k}}$ \\
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Even without the `\displaystyle`, the embedded contents still look a bit too large.

I have experimented this with several other "large" symbols such as integrals and products, and similarly tested them for both cases (with and without `\displaystyle`). The results all seem to have this problem.

Is there a way to make the result look more reasonable, for both with and without the `\displaystyle`? (I am currently thinking about the solution to make the "large" symbols only slightly larger than normal content inside the superscript or subscript, but there might be better ways.)

Comment: The best approach here "to make the result look more reasonable" is to define some symbol that denotes your sum, rather than placing the `\displaystyle` sum inside the super-/subscript.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: basically you just need to remove \displaystyle which is explicitly forcing the wrong layout

Answer (score 5):

First off: avoid complicated subscripts/superscripts as much as you can.

If you want to annoy your readers , then you have some choices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
x^{\sum_{i=0}^k a_i}_{\mathstrut} \\
x^{\sum\limits_{i=0}^k a_i}_{\mathstrut} \\
x^{\text{$\bigl(\,\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\bigr)$}}_{\mathstrut} \\
x^{\text{$\Bigl(\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\Bigr)$}}_{\mathstrut} \\
x^{\text{$\biggl(\,\sum\limits_{i=0}^k a_i\biggr)$}}_{\mathstrut} \\
x^{\scriptscriptstyle\text{$\Bigl(\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\Bigr)$}}_{\mathstrut} \\
x^{\scriptscriptstyle\text{$\biggl(\,\sum\limits_{i=0}^k a_i\biggr)$}}_{\mathstrut}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

In all of these I used a `\mathstrut` subscript that pushes the superscript a bit higher.

[image]

I'd exclude all that sport limits above and below the summation symbol (2, 5 and 7). I added 6 and 7 just for completeness, but the size of the characters is really too small.

Note the use of `\text` where parentheses are employed, in order to overcome the limitations of `\big` and friends that use fixed sizes everywhere.

If I had to choose among them, under physical threat, I'd go for 1 or 3. Maybe 4.

**Caveat** If you're using `\usepackage{lmodern}`, remember to also load `\usepackage{fixcmex}`. Try it and you'll see why.

Comment: Couldn’t agree more. Never put yourself in a position where you need to write something like this in a math equation. If no other options are available, you can always write `$x^{s}$, where $s=\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_i$` or something like that. Alternatively, I think something like `x^{\sum_i a_i}` or `x^{\sum a_i}` could be acceptable if there is no alternative around.

Comment: Or even just `x^{a_{0} + \dotsb + a_{k}}` ...

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use `\displaystyle` in the exponent term.
- Use parentheses to denote the scope of the exponent. If you use both `\big` sizing directives, be sure to apply the correction suggested by David Carlisle (see below).
- If `x` happens to be the base of the natural exponential, 2.71828...., consider writing `\exp(...)` rather than `e^{...}`. If this expression happens to occur in display-style math mode, be sure to enlarge the parentheses as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
% 'DC' in '\DCbig' stands for "David Carlisle" 
% See https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62653337
\def\DCbig#1{\left#1\vbox to7pt{}\right.\mkern-4mu} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& x^{\bigl(\sum_{i=0}^{k}2^i\bigr)} % parens and \sum not aligned correctly
  \quad
  x^{\DCbig(\sum_{i=0}^{k}2^i\DCbig)} \\ % <-- much better
&\displaystyle\exp\Bigl(\sum_{i=0}^{k}2^i \Bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your first example, it looks like either the sum or your parentheses are not vertically aligned on the math axis. I have not seen that before.

Comment: @mickep - I was puzzling over this issue -- the sum symbol and the parentheses not all being placed properly on the math axis -- as well. `\smash`ing the term `\sum_{i=0}^{k}` doesn't make a difference. The issue goes away, though, if I omit the `\bigl` and `\bigr` sizing directives. Not sure what the reason for this oddity could be.

Comment: David just explained [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62653337#62653337).

Comment: @mickep - Many thanks for initiating this inquiry (and for David Carlisle's solution!). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\scriptscriptstyle` to make superscripts/subscripts look smaller. Another approach is to rely on `\scalebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}


\begin{document}

A first approach using \verb|\scriptscriptstyle|:
\begin{align*}
  x^{\scriptscriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^{k} 2^i} \\
  x_{\scriptscriptstyle\sum_{i=0}^{k} 2^i} \\
\end{align*}

You could also rely on \verb|\scalebox|.

\begin{align*}
  x^{\scalebox{.5}{$\sum_{i=0}^{k} 2^i$}} \\
  x_{\scalebox{.5}{$\sum_{i=0}^{k} 2^i$}} \\  
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A drawback of using the `\scriptscriptstyle` approach is that while the size of the `\sum` symbol may be about right, the `i=0` and `k` terms -- which are also rendered in `\scriptscriptstyle` as there is no `\scriptscriptscriptstyle` in TeX -- look a bit too large next to `\sum`.

Comment: Added another approach